# WPF last column to stretch through DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

Is there any way to force the last column to stretch through the width of `DataGrid` WPF?

Because in some situation when the width of `DataGrid` is larger than the width of all columns cumulated, `DataGrid` behaves like containing a last empty column .

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Params}"  Width="Auto"
         AutoGenerateColumns="True" HeadersVisibility="None">
</DataGrid>

public List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> Params { get; set; }
```

[DataGrid with "an empty column"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5k2O.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could handle the `AutoGeneratedColumns` event and set the `Width` of the last column to `*` programmatically:

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
    dataGrid.Columns[dataGrid.Columns.Count - 1].Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Params}" 
          Width="Auto" AutoGenerateColumns="True" HeadersVisibility="None"
          AutoGeneratedColumns="DataGrid_AutoGeneratedColumns">
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `SfDataGrid` from [syncfusion](https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/datagrid/autosize-columns), the member to use is `ColumnSizer` (and not `Width`).

**Code behind:**

```
    private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, AutoGeneratingColumnArgs eventArgs)
    {
        string columnMappingName = eventArgs.Column.MappingName;

        if (columnMappingName == "Name")
        {
            eventArgs.Column.ColumnSizer = GridLengthUnitType.Star;
        }
    }
```

**XAML:**

```
<syncfusion:SfDataGrid AutoGeneratingColumn="DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn"/>
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).